# What's Wrong With My Gravity Form Drop Down?

Tags: gravity-forms-plugin, gravityforms

I am trying to create a form to put on my website, but it just isn't looking right. Here's what it looks like on [Safari](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Coyed.jpg). And here's what it looks like on [Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nUKRz.jpg). And here's what it looks like on [Firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FzscM.jpg).

I want it to look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FzscM.jpg) - just a simple, rectangular box. I'm having a hard time finding any information to figure this out.

Just in case it matters, I believe I should mention that these are Product Drop Downs, not the standard drop downs, with CSS code gf_left_third gf_middle_third and gf_right_third. I also used gf_simple_horizontal in the form settings.

How do I get the forms to look like a rectangular box from the default all across the board, regardless of the browser?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, browsers all have their own default form controls styling. Try downloading a stylesheet like [Normalize.css](https://www.google.com/search?q=normalize.css&oq=nor&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j0j69i57j69i60l3.880j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8), which you load before any of your stylesheets. It will do what it sounds like, normalizing the differences between browsers so that you get what you expect. But forms can still be tricky.

Here's where you can get a cdn link you can plug right into your index.html: [normalize cdn](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/normalize)